# Git pull upstream master messes develop branch

Tags: git

I'm working with a forking model. I have the original repository that I forked (upstream) and then I cloned this repository locally (origin).
When I'm done working on a branch locally, I create pull request from my origin to the upstream.

Later when a few changes are merged on the upstream (from my colleagues or myself), I want to pull them on my origin, I checkout on my master branch and I write in my terminal:

```
git pull upstream master
```

After this command, the changes are now on my origin. Nevertheless, it messes up the upstream develop branch. It removes the diff of changes between develop and master.

I don't get how it is possible.

Any idea ?

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. The *second* Git command is either `git merge` or `git rebase`: you choose which to use, via configuration options. This *always affects your current branch*, so run it with the correct branch checked out first. I personally prefer to *avoid* `git pull` and run `git fetch` and the second command myself, so that I control when the second command happens.

Comment: That is, you should consider `git fetch upstream`, not `git pull upstream master`. You can then decide when to run a `git rebase` or `git merge` command, or even *not run any such command at all*. This last is *probably* what you want.